# PHP - remote database connection

Tags: php, database

I have a hybrid app that runs with information from a database related to a portable server.

I need to retrieve information from my web server (different to the previous one) and I don't know how to do this.

I have a configuration file with the information and function to establish a database connection IN THE WEB SERVER.

What I'm trying to do is to include this config.php file into an app file to establish the connection from app server with web database.

I've tried cURL with no success.

Comment: So you have two servers - one is a web and database server and the other is a separate application server? You would like to connect from the application server to the web server's database?  You cannot serve the config.php for a remote include because it would be parsed as code without displaying the variables. It would be a major security challenge to configure it otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's exactly it. And I don't know how to do it and that's why I'm here looking for help - -'

Comment: If the web / database server is configured to accept remote database connections (usually to limited IPs by firewall rules), then the application server needs to have its own copy of the connection credentials. They cannot easily be shared.  One _possibility_ would be to automate an SSH connection between the two servers to retrieve the file securely, but that would be very slow. I would not recommend or attempt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i'm understanding you right you want to exchange the configuration of a database connection dynamically between two "hosts" ? Currently you are trying to download the config.php file via cURL ? This is not going to work, if you access the config.php via cURL it is processed by the webserver, so you probably get an empty response because the config.php has no output.

There are some solutions for this but I have serious security concerns. If you make your database configuration without any security measures available through a "webservice" this may result in very serious problems like dataleaks etc.

Please do not use the following in a production envorionment.

The keypoint is you have to build an array / object which holds all the data you need. Then you have to serialize it and transfer it to the second host.

A very simple and very insecure way to do this is to write a new script which can be reached through an GET request which responds with the serialized object. On the other host you simple unserialize the response and you have the object which contains your configurations.

The file you access from the remote host:

```
<?php
// Build your config array / object
$config["url"] = "your.database.host.com";
$config["port"] = "The port you use";
$config["other"] = "other stuff you want to transmit";
// serialize it and output it
echo serialize($config);
?>
```

Your remote host script:

```
<?php
// get the response with your config
$content = file_get_contents("<your host>");
// unserialisze it
$config = unserialize($content);
// database stuff
?>
```

I urge you not to transmit sensible information like this without a proper security concept. Maybe you could use ssh to copy the file or build a proper REST API with authentication and validation.